# Mojave dark mode not reflected properly on search bar

Tags: mojave, bug, dark-mode

As you can see in the picture, there's black text in search bar. I saw some pictures online but all of them shows white text in search bar when using Dark Mode. Is it some kind of color profile issue? How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: `I saw some pictures online but all of them shows white text in search bar when using Dark Mode.` Can you share some links?

Comment: It's not full white but you know you will see the change. Mine has this weird text and it's full black. https://cnet1.cbsistatic.com/img/CyfrJxl9iUxQ0WnikcYayO1J60I=/2018/06/27/3b3e0017-dec6-4859-8519-d7b272560bd1/mojave-dark-mode.jpg

Comment: Also see: https://youtu.be/dVitY2nC4Eo?t=60

Comment: @Sanjay What color does the search query appear in? Also try toggling modes. My color profile is Colour LCD if it matters. What is your OS Version?

Comment: It's Mojave 10.14.5 and search query's color is white.

Comment: @Sanjay The colour of the "search" is grey in mine too. As long as search query is white, I feel it is ignorable. Do you agree?

Comment: Yeah I agree. I just wanted to see if this was only limited to me. Anyway thanks.

Comment: OK, I just figured it out. `defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool NO` -> So running this will cause the problem.